# Thread.sleep not sleeping the current thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

In order to pause a process by a few seconds, I added `Thread.sleep` inside the run method of a Runnable. Below is the code.

```
@PostConstruct
public void initScheduler() {
    Runnable run = () -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                long productId = PRODUCT_ID_QUEUE.take();
                //Thread.sleep(5L);
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5L);
                try {
                    populateProductRatingsData(productId);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("Error while executing populateProductRatingsData with productId = " + productId, e);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Error while queue#take for reviews", e);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(run);
    t.start();
}
```

However, that pause didn't happen and then I switched to `Thread.currentThread().sleep(5L)` which was ineffective as well. So, in order to put delay I finally used

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.schedule(() -> populateProductRatingsData(productId), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

which resolved the issue.
So, Why `Thread.sleep` didn't work? or where was the mistake?

Thanks

Comment: It *does* work; you just sleep for `5 ms` when it looks like you want to sleep for `5 s`.

Comment: @Sam a question based on a misunderstanding should probably be deleted. It's unlikely that someone would stumble on this question and get much value out of it.

Comment: I'd argue someone else could make this same mistake fairly easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have used `Thread.sleep(5L);`, it would sleep only for 5 milliseconds and not seconds.

So you may not have observed the sleep although the thread has slept.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is actually working but the Unit of `Thread.sleep()`'s Argument is Millisecond as you can check in the [javadoc of Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)